# How to add content to a file using jsp in html?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have one jsp file and .txt file in a project. In jsp file there's one text field and a button. A user enters a text and clicks the button. I want the text in the text field to be stored in .txt file. 
Below is my code, what I m doing wrong here.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<%


%>
<body>
  <form method="post">
  Add:<input maxlength="120" name="text" size="40" type="url" />
  <input name="add" type="button" value="Add" /></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="add" type="button" value="Add" /></div>
```

Should be:

```
<input name="add" type="submit" value="Add" /></div>
```

Comment: I tested it and it is working. Are you sure you know where the file is located? Try printing the path.